# Jsoup redirects to start page

Tags: android, jsoup

I am connecting to a URL using

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect(params[0])
                                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.120 Safari/535.2")
                                .get();
```

But no matter what parameter I pass, it always return the same value example :
If I have a URL - `https://somewebsite.com/data?page=1`
It returns all the data from the page, but when I pass same URL with different `page` like `https://somewebsite.com/data?page=4`the websites redirects me to page 1.
Is there a method to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior (return to home page) may be a feature of the website you are triggering. Some websites do this exactly to prohibit users from doing "irregular" browse/navigation on them - letting users with one option only to paging - the "official" one, implemented on the proper site, most probably associated with a desired (from the owner's of the site perspective) UX, showing ads for example.

What you could try is to fetch only some tags inside **page X**, not the entire content of it, and check for the results. Maybe this can "fake" the redirection mechanism.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the insights, I will try to implement this